# Sending Attachments with an Email in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, file, email, debugging, ionic-framework

I have this code:

```
this.email.isAvailable().then((available: boolean) =>{
    if(available) {
    //Now we know we can send
    }
});

let email = {
    to: 'xxx@xxx.xxx',
    attachments: [
     'file:///C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/ZZZ_RonData.txt',
     'file:///C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/ZZZZ_LogIn_Ron.txt',
     'file:///C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/ZZZZ_LogOut_Ron.txt',
     'file:///C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/ZZ_signature.png'
    ],
    subject: 'User\'s Info',
    body: '',
    isHtml: true
};

// Send a text message using default options
this.email.open(email);
```

The files above are located in my downloads folder and my user is xxx. I am sure there no spelling mistakes. The problem is when I run this code, I get the email but with no attachments. What am I doing incorrectly?

***EDIT:*** Someone said I needed to put file before the location but I am not sure what he meant.

***EDIT:*** Is there an issue with the class path or the code that I have presented.

***EDIT:*** Are my paths the correct format for file directories?

This is the example given by Ionic:

```
let email = {
  to: 'max@mustermann.de',
  cc: 'erika@mustermann.de',
  bcc: ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com'],
  attachments: [
    'file://img/logo.png',
    'res://icon.png',
    'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...',
    'file://README.pdf'
  ],
  subject: 'Cordova Icons',
  body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
  isHtml: true
};
```

***FINAL EDIT:*** I am using Visual Studio an when I ctrl-click on the file path, the file comes up. This means the file directory is correct!